# HTML select from mysqli returning incomplete row data

Tags: php, html, select, mysqli

I am trying to populate a HTML select dropdown with data from a mysqli test table with a small number of "users", data is just an ID number, last name, and first name. I don't need to do anything with the information at present, just make sure everything is there. Code as follows;

```
require("connection.php");

$query = "SELECT last FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo '<p>There are '.$num.' users in the database';

echo '<p><label for="users">Select User</label>
    <select id="users" name="users">
    <option> -- Select User -- </option>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  foreach ($row as $u) {
    echo '<option>'.$u['last'].'</option>';
  }
}

echo '</select></p>';

?>
```

When I run the script, I can see that the $num variable prints out the correct number of "users", but for some strange reason, the dropdown is only showing the first letter of the user's last name (to clarify, there are five options available, but each is just one letter of the record instead of the whole last name). This seems very odd to me, just wondering if there are any obvious errors anyone can see above.

Comment: What is the foreach loop inside the while loop supposed to be good for? Makes no sense. Remove it, and echo `$row['last']` instead.

Comment: CBroe, when I do that, there are five options in the menu, except all of them are blank.

#edit - apologies, removed that but had the wrong syntax. Fixed. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: What exactly are you reading from the database then? Your SQL statement appears to contain only one single column, yet you say something about _“data is just an ID number, last name, and first name”_ - what does that mean then?

Comment: Calm down bud. Just trying to get one thing to work before I add more elements.

Comment: remove foreach from the code

Comment: Common Sense, ya, did that, all good now. Thank you.